# Visual Studio 2017 asking for Office Devleoper Tools 2015

Tags: visual-studio

I have installed VS 2017 enterprise... I tried to open a SharePoint solution and is says I need to update Office Developer Tools... when I try to update by clicking the button I get an error that 2015 community edition or greater needs to be installed.   I have 2017?

Any ideas on how to get rid of the error so I can open my project?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and found the answer in [this blog post](https://timeisnet.wordpress.com/2017/04/18/visual-studio-2017-sharepoint-projects-update-required/). The problem was that my .csproj files contained the line:

```
<MinimumOfficeToolsVersion>14.6</MinimumOfficeToolsVersion>
```

Once I removed this line, I was able to load the project files properly.

If you're still having problems opening the project, be sure Visual Studio Tools for Office are installed for Visual Studio 2017. You can install them by opening Visual Studio Installer, modifying your installation, checking "Office/SharePoint Development" and then being sure "Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)" is selected under "Optional" on the right: